# Linux freezes and crashes due to SSD

Tags: freeze, crash

I've used Ubuntu, Mint, Kali and Arch Linux, endeavor OS and Manjaro, they all have the same problem. When I installed Linux on my external HDD, I realized that this problem was caused by the SSD. I booted Linux from the HDD, at that time it wasn't reading the internal SSD, when I double-clicked it, it crashed after a few minutes. But there is no problem when it does not read the SSD. My problem is that I am using the computer normally and it freezes after a random period of time, everything freezes completely. The only solution is to turn off the computer with the power button and turn it on again.

Acer Aspire 3
Ryzen 2500U.
Radeon 535 2 GB.
16 GB DDR3 RAM.
-SSD: MicroN_1100_MtfddAV256TBN 256.0 GB.

Comment: Are you saying the computer crashes every time you access the ssd but not if you don’t? If you have the same problem with multiple OS’s, it suggests a hardware fault with the ssd.

Comment: Can't I fix it?  With grub settings?

Comment: Many with SSD issues find UEFI firmware update & SSD firmware update resolve issue. Do you have latest available firmware from vendors? What version of Ubuntu. I have 22.04 and it now has VMD driver for SSD.

Comment: I guess it also depends on how old that SSD is. SSDs have a lifecycle in terms of how many times data can be rewritten on them. In other words, they can get literally worn out. You should consider therefore how much usage the SSD had already seen. If it's truly old, continuing using it will bring about a high risk of losing your data. On a related note, that is why I buy only "NAS-grade" SSDs. Those are optimized towards 3x as many rewrite cycles as normal ones, but at the cost of the data transfer speed. Given how fast SSDs are in general, I find this speed tradeoff totally acceptable.

Comment: Please be specific with release details; you maybe using an inappropriate *software stack* (ie. Ubuntu product/release) for your stated hardware, but you've not told us what you're using. When you say it freezes; is that just the GUI/display?  were you able to direct the kernel (Linux) via SysRq and like commands bypassing UI (ie. system still operates; just frozen screen/UI)